# "Нет" в роли сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

Есть 3 времени у глагола (не) *быть* в роли сказуемого в безличном предложении:
*не было*, *не будет*, *не есть* (= *нет*).

В речи не употребляют "не есть", а вместо него говорят "нет". То есть *нет* — это тупо замена "не было" в настоящем времени. Существуют ли примеры с *нет* в роли сказуемого, где такая замена невозможна?

Например:
`Сахара больше нет / не было.` Замена возможна, смысл сохраняется с учетом перехода во времени.

Comment: Пишут что: сахара нет - нет сказуемое. Я бы ответил, что: нет - подлежащее,- Что? - нет. - Нет как? - больше, определение. - Нет чего? - сахара, дополнение. Хотя, может, сахара больше не наблюдается - то есть нет. Хотя сочетание "есть нет" странное. И "сахара да" не скажешь.

Comment: От подлежащего можно задать вопрос к сказуемому типа что делал. Сравните: На столе мешок сахара. На столе нет сахара. Две совершенно разные конструкции

Comment: Чем разные? и в любом случае в первом - одно подлежащее, без сказуемого, как вопросы задавать?не ясно к чему 1-е утверждение.

Comment: Мешок что делает? Находится на столе. Нет что делает? Почувствуйте разницу.

Comment: То есть в предложении "на столе мешок сахара" есть невидимое сказуемое "находится"? Может тогда "на столе находится мешок сахара" - сразу так?

Comment: разумеется есть. Просто не принято в русском языке его проставлять

Comment: Что значит не принято? Кем не принято?

Comment: Не принято, значит всегда можно подставить без потери смысла, чего не скажешь о На столе нет сахара.

Comment: А по-моему, смысл таки меняется. "На столе мешок сахара" - не требует глагола в принципе. А вот, "на столе находится мешок сахара" - это совсем другая история, смысл меняется. На столе мешок сахара - бессубъектное предложение. На столе находится мешок сахара - появляется субъект, который этот мешок находит. Не могу сказать, теряется ли смысл или преобретается, но смысл у предложений разный.

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем я разжевываю базовые вещи. Читайте про нулевую связку что ли http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0 До свидания.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вот с этого момента начинается ересь: "В русском языке нулевая связка заменяет формы настоящего времени индикатива глагола быть."

Answer (score 0):

Автомат ( https://textovod.com/syntax ) полагает, что «нет» вполне годится на роль сказуемого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]